# Cleaner way to selectively multiply pandas DataFrame values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given this example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, isna
from numpy import nan


df = DataFrame([
    {'id': '1', 'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'z': 4},
    {'id': '5', 'x': 6, 'y': 7, 'z': 8},
    {'id': '9', 'x': 10, 'y': 11, 'z': 12}
]).set_index('id')

factors = DataFrame([
    {'id': '5', 'x': nan, 'z': 3},
    {'id': '9', 'x': 0.2, 'z': nan},
]).set_index('id')

for row_id in factors.index:
    for col in factors.columns:
        if not isna(factors[col][row_id]):
            df[col][row_id] *= factors[col][row_id]
```

Where the values in `df` are multiplied by non-NaN values from `factors`, is there a cleaner way to do this with `pandas`? (or `numpy` for that matter) I had a look at `.mul()`, but that doesn't appear to allow me to do what's required here.

Additionally, what if factors contains rows with an `id` that's not in `df`, e.g.:

```
factors = DataFrame([
    {'id': '5', 'x': nan, 'z': 3},
    {'id': '13', 'x': 2, 'z': 4},
]).set_index('id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem right, you can use `.update` + `.mul`:

```py
df.update(df.mul(factors))
```

Prints:

```
      x   y     z
id               
1   2.0   3   4.0
5   6.0   7  24.0
9   2.0  11  12.0
```

---

For the second example (if factors contains rows with an id that's not in df) this prints:

```
     x   y     z
id              
1    2   3   4.0
5    6   7  24.0
9   10  11  12.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm accepting this response, as it's exactly what I was looking for - I missed the possibility of `.update()` combined with `.mul()`. Any idea why the result with the extra line causes the type of the `'x'` column to change unexpectedly?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say "pandas (or numpy for that matter)" let me suggest [`xarray`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/), which is the PyData answer to N-D labeled arrays. xarray is specifically designed for problems involving labeled arrays with multiple corresponding dimensions like this, where you want all of the conveniences of pandas indices with the performance and broadcasting behaviors of numpy arrays.

For this problem specifically, you could dump the dataframes into xarray [DataArrays](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html#dataarray):

```py
In [1]: from pandas import DataFrame, isna
   ...: from numpy import nan
   ...:
   ...:
   ...: df = DataFrame([
   ...:     {'id': '1', 'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'z': 4},
   ...:     {'id': '5', 'x': 6, 'y': 7, 'z': 8},
   ...:     {'id': '9', 'x': 10, 'y': 11, 'z': 12}
   ...: ]).set_index('id')
   ...:
   ...: factors = DataFrame([
   ...:     {'id': '5', 'x': nan, 'z': 3},
   ...:     {'id': '9', 'x': 0.2, 'z': nan},
   ...: ]).set_index('id')

In [2]: da = df.stack().to_xarray()

In [3]: da
Out[3]:
<xarray.DataArray (id: 3, level_1: 3)>
array([[ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [10, 11, 12]])
Coordinates:
  * id       (id) object '1' '5' '9'
  * level_1  (level_1) object 'x' 'y' 'z'

In [4]: factors_da = factors.stack().to_xarray()

In [5]: factors_da
Out[5]:
<xarray.DataArray (id: 2, level_1: 2)>
array([[nan, 3. ],
       [0.2, nan]])
Coordinates:
  * id       (id) object '5' '9'
  * level_1  (level_1) object 'x' 'z'
```

then you can broadcast `factors_da` to be indexed like `da`:

```py
In [6]: factors_da = factors_da.reindex_like(da)
   ...: factors_da
Out[6]:
<xarray.DataArray (id: 3, level_1: 3)>
array([[nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, 3. ],
       [0.2, nan, nan]])
Coordinates:
  * id       (id) object '1' '5' '9'
  * level_1  (level_1) object 'x' 'y' 'z'
```

Then multiply them together (first filling factors with 1 so missing values are preserved):

```py
In [7]: da * factors_da.fillna(1)
Out[7]:
<xarray.DataArray (id: 3, level_1: 3)>
array([[ 2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 6.,  7., 24.],
       [ 2., 11., 12.]])
Coordinates:
  * id       (id) object '1' '5' '9'
  * level_1  (level_1) object 'x' 'y' 'z'
```

Then you can always dump this back into pandas:

```py
In [9]: (da * factors_da.fillna(1)).to_series().unstack('level_1')
Out[9]:
level_1    x     y     z
id
1        2.0   3.0   4.0
5        6.0   7.0  24.0
9        2.0  11.0  12.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - in my case, I would not be able to do this due to project restrictions, but I do like `xarray` in general. For anyone not constrained in library choice, taking the `xarray` route should definitely be a consideration.